# hide list items in dropdownlist based on checkboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox, listitem

I have a report with 4 checkboxes that changes what the report displays. There is also a search feature so the user can search for certain companies. But depending on what checkbox is checked, only certain search options in the dropdownlist need to be displayed.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSearchBy">
     <asp:ListItem Text="All Job Owners" Value="null" ></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Job Owner" Value="Customer" ></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Col Member" Value="Col Member" ></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Del Member" Value="Del Member" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

So depending on which checkbox is selected I only want certain ListItems shown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#rbNormal').change(function() {
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                 //hide third listitem
            }
        });

        $('#rbDailyReport').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                 //hide third and forth listitem
            }
        });
    });
```

**EDIT**
Ok so I used add and remove. `rbNormal` is the default option that is always selected unless the user clicks a different button. When I click `rbDailyReport` it should display the forth list item in the dropdownlist but it doesn't. It is still removed.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        if ($('#rbNormal').is(':checked')) {
            $("#ddlSearchBy option[value='Col Member']").remove();
            $("#ddlSearchBy option[value='Del Member']").remove();
        }

        $('#rbDailyReport').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#ddlSearchBy option[value='Del Member']").add();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: you will have to remove/add option elements as needed

Comment: @Igor can you show some code?

Comment: @Igor please see the edit to my question. I used add and remove but it is not adding a list item back in

Comment: @user123456789 - of course not. After remove, `$("#ddlSearchBy option[value='Del Member']")` has nothing.

Comment: @Igor then how do I show the list item again?

Comment: `$("#ddlSearchBy).append("<option value='Del Member'>Del Member</option>");`

Comment: @Igor thank you this worked

Comment: I will say this one last time before going on my merry way: You need to create a temp list, or store the original options (as @jnoreiga suggests), and add/delete based on your selection criteria. Adding hard-wired HTML appends is a *very* poor solution for maintenance. Always drive it from the content provided by the server and do not duplicate effort. With the "accepted" answer you now have to maintain your options in 2 places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var hideoptions = function(indexes) {
   var $select = $('#ddlSearchBy'),
     existinghtml = $select.data('originalhtml'),
     allindices = indexes.split(',');
   if (typeof(existinghtml) == "undefined" || existinghtml == null) {
     existinghtml = $select.html();
     $select.data('originalhtml', existinghtml);
   }
   $select.children().remove();
   $select.append(existinghtml);
   $select.children().filter(function(index) {
     return allindices.indexOf(index.toString()) > -1;
   }).remove();


 };
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#rbNormal').change(function() {
     if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       //hide third listitem
       hideoptions('2');
     }
   });

   $('#rbDailyReport').change(function() {
     if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       //hide third and forth listitem
       hideoptions('2,3');
     }
   });
 });
```

Comment: You cannot `hide()` `option` elements in a `select`. Not all browsers support it. You need to remove/add items instead.

Comment: Interesting approach... have remove DV and await testing.

Comment: thanks for answer. It works when I want to hide one ListItem but trying to hide two doesn't work: ` hideoptions('2,3');`

Comment: I was using the eq method incorrectly. I updated it to use filter instead.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove/add option elements as needed.

```
$("#ddlSearchBy option[value='Del Member']").remove();
```

and

```
$("#ddlSearchBy).append("<option value='Del Member'>Del Member</option>");
```

Comment: This will always move the new items to the end, defeating any sorting. IMHO this is not a complete solution (and very hard-wired to the HTML).

Answer (score 0):

Try my below code , i hope it should solve your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select id="dropdown1" style="width:200px;">
  <option value="" name="">Dropdpwn Value 1</option>
  <option value="" name="">Dropdown Value 2</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="" checked />
<br />
<select id="dropdown2" style="width:200px;">
  <option value="" name="">Dropdpwn Value 1</option>
  <option value="" name="">Dropdpwn Value 2</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" value="" checked />
<br />
<select id="dropdown3" style="width:200px;">
  <option value="" name="">Dropdpwn Value 1</option>
  <option value="" name="">Dropdpwn Value 2</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" value="" checked />
<br />
<select id="dropdown4" style="width:200px;">
  <option value="" name="">Dropdpwn Value 1</option>
  <option value="" name="">Dropdpwn Value 2</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="check4" value="" checked />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#check1").click(function() {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
          $("#dropdown1").show();
       } else {
          $("#dropdown1").hide();  
       }
    });
    $("#check2").click(function() {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
          $("#dropdown2").show();
       } else {
          $("#dropdown2").hide();  
       }
    });
    $("#check3").click(function() {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
          $("#dropdown3").show();
       } else {
          $("#dropdown3").hide();  
       }
    });
    $("#check4").click(function() {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
          $("#dropdown4").show();
       } else {
          $("#dropdown4").hide();  
       }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So your solution is to duplicate ASP lists, client-side, with one list for each possible option selected? Sorry, but this is a terrible idea and incompatible with the ASP list shown :(

Comment: Let me understand , there are 4 checkboxes and 1 dropdown list.. Right ? When any checkbox checked , then dropdown values must change according to that checked value ? Am i right ?

Comment: How were you expecting the 4 lists to post back correctly as a single list expected by ASP?